# Python 2.7.10 Tkinter curly brackets around text in textbox

Tags: python, tkinter

I have made the GUI and everything runs fine but when the text comes up it's in curly brackets

Example code:

```
message = "You need to burn another", wfmlvl - fmlvl, "logs to level up"
```

I am making a firemaking calculator for Runescape, now I was wondering how to get rid of the curly brackets around the text in the text box. `wfmlvl` and `fmlvl` are variables set in the entry boxes.

I have made it so what they enter is set to `fmlvl1` and `wfmlvl1` e.g.

```
def reveal(self):

    fmlvl1 = self.fmlvl.get()
    wfmlvl = self.wfmlvl.get()

    fmlvl = int(fmlvl1)
    wfmlvl = inf(wfmlvl1)
```

when the text is displayed it looks like this:

> {You need to burn another} 45 {logs to level up}

How can I get rid of the curly brackets?

Comment: use `+` to concatenate strings. for example `"Number " + str(7) + " brings happiness"` And don't forget to add spaces - concatenate doesn't work like `print`

Comment: kk thx this will help me later on

Comment: Please do not ask for urgency in questions - most helpers here are volunteers, and they generally answer at their leisure. Also, all questions are of equal importance.

Comment: u helped me more than him lol thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create your message like this:

```
message = "You need to burn another {} logs to level up".format(wfmlvl - fmlvl)
```

Comment: You  can [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) an answer that solves your problem.